# Disable imageview zooming in a zoomable scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

My question is how can i disable zooming of an imageView, witch is in a zoomable scrollview ?
I would like to zoom into an scrollview with keeping the same size for some imageviews inside it.
Help !

Comment: sahaninoo , your questions is little confusing. Can you please let us know what do you mean by zooming of imageview?

Comment: When using a UIScrollView and setting it up to zoom, all subviews of UIScrollView are being scaled, too.
i want to disable zoom for some subviews (image view) of the UIScrollView

Comment: So your main view is having few imageviews in it which you don't want to zoom while zooming the scroll view is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach :-

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
   return canZoom?view:nil;
}
```

May this helps you !